# Github does not have ssh key, but I can still login without password

Tags: git, github, ssh, public-key

My Github account currently does not have any SSH keys (I believe it previously did have a key, but I deleted it a while ago). However, whenever I use `git push` and `git pull` from my personal computer, they do not require me to enter a password, and they run without any trouble.

1. How is this possible if the Github server doesn't have the public key?
2. Can I allow password-less `push` and `pull` from another computer without uploading a public key for it?

[image: Github keys]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first what you get with:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote -v
```

If you see an URL starting with https://... , then SSH keys are not involved/needed at all.

Your credentials (GitHub user account/password) are probably cached by your credential helper. Check which helper is used with:

```
git config credential.helper
```

Comment: Fascinating! I do indeed see `https://` instead of `git@`. I ran `git config --list --show-origin` and it shows I have a single solitary system-level config in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig` that I never knew existed! When I run `git config credential.helper` it returns that system-level config, called `osxkeychain`.

Comment: How did `osxkeychain` obtain my Github credentials?

Comment: @efthimio I supposed it asks for said credential just once in the past, and keep them ever since.